# How can I pass a variable from the controller to a partial?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, controller

I rendering a view partial like this.

```
<%= render :partial => 'resources/positions', :controller => 'resources',
                         :action => 'this_is_a_test',
                         :locals => {:id_resource => 42} %>
```

resources_controller.rb

```
def this_is_a_test
    @test1 = "batman"
    render :partial => 'positions'
  end
```

_positions.html.erb

```
<%= @test1 %>
```

but the variable @test1 is empty. Do you have any idea ?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand how exactly you're calling what. If in the controller you run `this_is_a_test`, you're not passing the partial any variables. The instance variable will not be passed to the partial. And why would you need the JS file for that? Where is it getting loaded?

Comment: slhck: I removed the js.

Answer (score 1):

```
def this_is_a_test
  render :partial => 'positions', :locals => { :test1 => "batman" }
end
```

and change `_position.html.erb` to

```
<%= test1 %>
```

Comment: Do you understand why the OP would need the JavaScript or included it in the question?

Comment: sorens you mean <%= @test1 %> or <%= local_assigns[:test1] %> ?

Comment: @user1560922 No, `test1` should be enough. You can use `local_assigns` to test if the local variable really exists, e.g. `if local_assigns.has_key?(:test1)`.

Comment: undefined local variable or method `test1'. when I put <%= test1 %>

Comment: @user1560922 you need to debug what exactly is going on. perhaps your partial is not where you think it is? if you put static text in the partial, do you see it when you GET that route in your web browser? partials are relative to controllers so if you are doing this in `resources_controller.rb`, the partial must be in `app/views/resources/_positions.html.erb`. if that is not the case, then you need to specify the path where the controller can find that partial.